# Problema con QT slotSignal

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt

Me encontré con un código el cual pide que lo modifiques para poder generar un slotSignal de la clase A conectado con la clase B. ¿Alguien podría explicarme el como hacerlo y la demostración?

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, QObject


class A(QObject):
    __parent__ = None

    def __init__(self, parent: QObject):
        super().__init__()
        self.__parent__ = parent

    def slotSignal(self):
        print('Señal recibida en la clase A.')
    

class B(QObject):
     signal = pyqtSignal()

     def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.__a__ = A(self)

     def emitSignal(self):
        self.signal.emit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
     b = B()
     b.emitSignal()
```

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que se desea es un ejemplo de como funcionan las señales y slots entonces tienes las siguientes deficiencias:

- Debes realizar una conexión con la sintaxis siguiente:

  ```py
  sender.signal.connect(receiver.slot)
  ```
- Las señales y slots necesitan un Qt eventloop que tu no has creado.

Con lo anterior la solución es:

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, QCoreApplication, QObject


class A(QObject):
    def slotSignal(self):
        print("Señal recibida en la clase A.")


class B(QObject):
    signal = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._a = A(self)
        self.signal.connect(self._a.slotSignal)

    def emitSignal(self):
        self.signal.emit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QCoreApplication([])
    b = B()
    b.emitSignal()
    app.exec_()
```